# Checkbox using xpath not accessible

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, checkbox

I am trying to access a checkbox titled "Cooperative Agreement (968)" on a website (grants.gov). The URL is [this](https://www.grants.gov/web/grants/search-grants.html).

It looks like there are two HTML elements on the HTML page. The second HTML is contained in `#document`.

I don't know what `#document` means, but I think it is where the issue is, because, I can get anything outside of `#document`, but nothing inside of it.

This is my current code:

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get('https://www.grants.gov/web/grants/search-grants.html')

time.sleep(3)
print('go')
cooperative_agreement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
'/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input')

print(cooperative_agreement.text)
```

I am using dev tools on chrome to get the XPath for everything. If you go to the URL and go to dev tools on chrome and try to get the XPath for the checkbox titled "Cooperative Agreement (968)" you will see the issue I am having.

This is my first question on StackOverflow. Please let me know if you need more info on something! Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it correct the element is inside iframe you need to switch it first.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`
Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe#embeddedIframe")))  

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[.//label[contains(., 'Cooperative Agreement')]]/input[1]"))).click()

#Jump out from iframe
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Yooooo, that fixed it, Thank you so much!